# how to use find in scp command

Tags: ssh, find, scp

I would like to use scp command fo transfer some files from remote server to local machine. The problem I have is to find the files and then direct them to scp command. I don't want to generate an ssh-key on the server, so I have to use the command from the local machine to perform the task.

Actually, I need something like below: 

`` scp username@server_IP:/path/to/file/`find . -ctime -1 -type f` ./ ``

The problem is that find command does not work.

Please advice.

Comment: If you don't want to generate an ssh key on the server (i.e. cannot connect from the server to your local machine) then you need two steps: 1) `ssh` to the remote server and issue the `find` to select the files and remember the file list locally, and 2) issue `scp` with that file list. `scp` accepts just filenames, nothing else. And `ssh` accepts just commands. You need to combine the two.

Comment: Yes, you need to use ssh, but you can combine it into one command.  I tend to do this, ssh username@server_IP '(cd /path/to/file; find . -ctime -1 -type f -print | cpio -o)' | cpio -pdm    This will use a cpio stream to copy the files from the remote server to your server.  Give it a shot.

Comment: it is worked but not complete!
```
ssh asterisk '(cd /root/backup/ ; find . -ctime -1 -type f)'
```
with cpio added to the end, the entire screen starts to flashing!!!
but I still have the problem. I have to scp the output to local machine .

Comment: ```
moji@ThinkPad:~/test$ ssh asterisk '(cd /root/backup/ ; find . -ctime -1 -type f)'
./ip-route_2018-10-03.txt
./etc-asterisk_2018-10-03.tar.gz
./var-lib-tftpboot_2018-10-03.tar.gz
./dhcp_2018-10-03.tar.gz
moji@ThinkPad:~/test$ ssh asterisk '(cd /root/backup/ ; find . -ctime -1 -type f)' scp ???
```

Comment: [This link](https://www.netroby.com/view/3602) plus the comment of @LewisM helped me make a working one-liner :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a local target directory

  ```
  mkdir /path/to/targetdir
  ```
- Identify the remote source directory `/path/to/sourcedir`
- Run the following one-liner (edited with the correct source and target directories and `user@ip-address` for the server),

  ```
  ssh username@ip-adress '(cd /path/to/sourcedir; find . -print | cpio -oBav -Hcrc)' | ( cd /path/to/targetdir && cpio -ivumd )
  ```

Comment: Worked. Thank you @sudodus


`ssh asterisk '(cd /root/backup/; find . -mtime -1 -type f | cpio -oBav -Hcrc)' | ( cd /home/moji/test && cpio -ivumd )`
worked properly.

I don't know about cpio and it's options. must read about it. :D

Comment: @MJtaleghani, I'm glad it works for you :-) You find descriptions of the options in [this link](https://www.netroby.com/view/3602) and more details in the manual `man cpio`